# Ignore duplicate records in case when statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I table two table where I want to take only unique records. I have created a short SQL query which is as below:

```
Declare @tempTable AS TABLE(Country VARCHAR(10),PatientId INT) 
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES ('India',1)

Declare @tempStatus AS TABLE(PatientId INT, status VARCHAR(2)) 
INSERT INTO @tempStatus VALUES (1,'NA'),(1,'A'),(1,'D'),(1,'R'),(1,'A')

SELECT t.Country,t.PatientId,Status= (CASE 
        WHEN ts.status='A' THEN 'A'
        WHEN ts.status='NA' OR ts.status='D' THEN 'NA'
        ELSE 'R' END)
FROM @tempTable t
LEFT JOIN @tempStatus ts ON t.PatientId=ts.PatientId
```

It return me data as

[image]

**Scenario :**

1. If there is a status as 'A' then it will take as one row for all 5 records as shown in the output.
2. If there is as status 'NA' or 'D' then it will take that status and ignore other rows.

On the basis of condition it should just return the output as:

```
Country     PatientId       Status
India       1               A
```

Can someone help on this to ignore the duplicates in case statement.

Comment: Moving the goal posts after getting answers is severely frowned upon; especially when it invalidates those answers. Though this now looks like you want `MIN` not `MAX`. You also, however, don't state what needs to happen if `'A'` isn't in the data.

Comment: @Larnu It will take that status as a single row. But if there is 'A' then it will only take one record. I will update my question again with scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to wrap your `CASE` **expression** in a `MAX`:

```sql
SELECT t.Country,
       t.PatientId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ts.status='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status --Made this shorter
FROM @tempTable t
     LEFT JOIN @tempStatus ts ON t.PatientId=ts.PatientId
GROUP BY t.Country,
         t.PatientId;
```

Comment: appreciated. I need to update my question as I have multiple conditions. It will work for this two but I forgot to add other.

Comment: @Lifewithsun . . . You shouldn't change the question after it has been answered.  It is much better to ask a *new* question.  You have dissuaded many other people from answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for some kind of DISTINCT result with joins based on some conditions. If i got it right after 5 times reading.

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(Country VARCHAR(10),PatientId INT) 
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES ('India',1), ('Foo', 2) -- added dummy

-- renamed PatientId to PId for easier writing
DECLARE @tempStatus TABLE(PId INT, status VARCHAR(2))
-- added dummy data
INSERT INTO @tempStatus VALUES (1,'NA'),(1,'A'),(1,'D'),(1,'R'),(1,'A'),(2,'NA'),(2,'D'),(2,'R')


SELECT DISTINCT -- only unique rows
    Country,
    t.PatientId,
    -- only D is replaced in your example with NA, else default status
    CASE WHEN ts.status = 'D' THEN 'NA' ELSE ts.status END AS Status
FROM @tempTable t
LEFT JOIN @tempStatus ts ON 
    ( -- first condition
        (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM @tempStatus WHERE status = 'A' and PId = PatientId) IS NOT NULL
        AND PId = PatientId and status = 'A'
    ) OR
    ( -- second condition
        (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM @tempStatus WHERE status = 'A' and PId = PatientId) IS NULL
        AND PId = PatientId
    )
```

- PatientId 1 will only return one row, with A
- PatientId 2 will return 2 rows with NA and R